# How to model the three phase PWM rectifier?

Tags: pwm, power-electronics, rectifier, three-phase, modeling

I have been working on a dynamic model of the three phase PWM rectifier also known as active front end (AFE.)

Circuit diagra:

[image]

I have decided to solve that task this way:

1. Choose some variables as a state variables (common approach is to choose the energy related variables as the state variables i.e. currents of the inductors and voltages of the capacitors.)
2. Make a list of all the possible switching states of the converter.
3. Write down the differential equations for the state variables chosen in step 1 in each switching state of the converter.

According to step 1, I have chosen following state variables \$i_{ag}, i_{bg}, i_{cg},v_{bus}\$. There are \$2^3=8\$ possible switching states which are fully determined by the states of the control signals \$[S_a, S_b, S_c]\$ (\$S_i = 0\$ in case switch is open and \$S_i = 1\$ in case switch is closed) assuming that the high switch and low switch in the same phase works complementary. The set of differential equations for each switching state:

- State 0 i.e. \$[S_a, S_b, S_c] = [0, 0, 0]\$

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}i_{ag}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{L_f}\left(v_{a0} - R_f\cdot i_{ag} - v_{ag} - v_{n0}\right) = \frac{1}{L_f}\left(- R_f\cdot i_{ag} - v_{ag} - v_{n0}\right)\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}i_{bg}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{L_f}\left(v_{b0} - R_f\cdot i_{bg} - v_{bg} - v_{n0}\right) = \frac{1}{L_f}\left(- R_f\cdot i_{bg} - v_{bg} - v_{n0}\right)\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}i_{cg}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{L_f}\left(v_{c0} - R_f\cdot i_{cg} - v_{cg} - v_{n0}\right) = \frac{1}{L_f}\left(- R_f\cdot i_{cg} - v_{cg} - v_{n0}\right)\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}v_{bus}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{C}\cdot i_c = \frac{1}{C}\cdot\left(i_{dc}-i_{gdc}\right) = \frac{1}{C}\cdot i_{dc}
$$

The problem I have is how to determine the \$v_{n0}\$ voltage.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following equations:

$$\begin{bmatrix}V_a \\ V_b \\ V_c\end{bmatrix}=R_f
\begin{bmatrix}I_{ag} \\ I_{bg} \\ I_{cg}\end{bmatrix}+L_f\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}
\begin{bmatrix}I_{ag} \\ I_{bg} \\ I_{cg}\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}V_{ax} \\ V_{bx} \\ V_{cx}\end{bmatrix}
$$

where \$V_{[a,b,c]x}\$ are the voltages taken from the points between \$L_f\$ and the sources and referenced to ground. This will take care of the neutral point. However, I don't see anything dynamical in your equations, just the usual form for a switching bridge with series RL.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Does it mean that \$V_{ax} = V_{ag} - V_{n0}\$ as far as the relationship to my circuit diagram?

Comment: Does it not? \$V_{n0}\$ is referenced to ground, and \$V_{[a,b,c]g}\$ are across the sources, so, naturally, \$V_{[a,b,c]x}\$ is the two in series.